# Windows SaveAs dlg with OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT doesn't detect file deletions?

Tags: winapi, prompt, overwrite, savefiledialog

I'm using a perfectly usual SaveAs dialog (in Delphi Win32 XE2, the system is Win 7 /64), setting OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT (or the Delphi wrapper's equivalent `dlgSave.Options := [ofPathMustExist, ofOverwritePrompt];`.  So if I select an existing file, the dialog asks for confirmation to overwrite the file.

Everything works as it should except for one silly thing:  when I choose a file, then delete that file right in the same dialog, then press OK, the dialog still asks if it's ok to overwrite the (already deleted) file.  Apparently, the dialog checks file existence against a pre-loaded list, not the file system.  The problem is not specific to Delphi and can be shown very easily even in Notepad:

- Run Notepad.exe
- Enter some text
- Save as a file
- Click File Save As again, in the SaveAs dialog do:

  - Click on the same file to select it,
  - Right-click and delete the file,
  - click OK.

The file is no longer there, but you still get the overwrite prompt.

Can anybody please suggest a way to work around this minor but annoying Windows bug?  I assume some message processing / callbacks / hooks might be required?  A way of checking the file presence in code while the modal SaveAs dialog is open?

Comment: Why bother? How often is this going to happen?

Comment: That's what I tell myself. This is certainly not a big problem, but it just plain wrong and, once I noticed the bug, it does bother me. Almost any Windows app uses file save dialog API, so if there is a workaround, having it here for everybody to use might be worth the trouble.

Comment: Well, rather than spending too much time, maybe remove the flag completely and test for existence after the dialog is closed. Then you can prompt with a message box yourself. That would be easier than hooking or callbacks and would still work if/when the bug is fixed in Windows.

Comment: Seems like a non-issue to me.  Can't imagine a user being bothered by such a scenario, especially when it was a user action that helped cause it.